# When the users are on the same webpage, is it possible that one user has clicked on a button and that will notify all other users?

Tags: javascript, notifications, page-refresh

Just like the title says. I want to create a shared online timer for my friends and say when one of my friends clicked the "refresh timer" button, ideally that all my other friends' page should get automatically refreshed with the new timer, or a notification saying that the timer has refreshed and require them to refresh the page.

I think at least the latter one is possible since when you get a comment of your question on Stackoverflow, you will get notified somewhere in the page telling you there's a new comment.

How to achieve this functionality? In JS or? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need server-side logic of some sorts. Your best bet would be to store the 'last update' in a database, and then have your script update the value when someone clicks the button. Then your page would need to query the database on a repeated basis to check when the last update was.

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

using Javascript setInterval when the page is loaded, if you're not using MySQL, check a notepad for the text `update`(or whatever you want) and when it's found, clear it and then run whatever code


When the user presses a button, have it write to the file `update`(the same thing as above)

Comment: That's smart. I did use this method to create the timer but I didn't realize that it could be used this way. I will try and come back. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There would be 2 ways to go about it:

- Simpler one would be to use polling through setInterval and look for changes on the backend.
- A more accurate way would be to use Websockets which relay information to the clients that the timer has been reset.

Your choice of tool would depend on how complex you're willing to let it be